# What is the difference between audible and spoken feedback for accessibility in Android?

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Android documentation mentions that the

> "accessibilityFeedbackType"

can be either

> "feedbackAudible"" or "feedbackSpoken"

among others.

I am not sure what is the difference between these two and the doc doesnt provide further explanation for the same.
Could anyone please confirm?

Reference link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#FEEDBACK_AUDIBLE

Answer (score 1):

Audible: beeps, blips, earcons.

Spoken: words.